# Including '@' in ASP.NET MVC URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a URL which contains '@' (to reference langitudes and longitudes) however, when it is being referenced using href an error occurs near '@'

Are there any escape sequences that can be used?

Sorry for asking such a simple question!

Comment: @KhairulIslam Exactly what code are you expecting OP to show us? Code does not need to be shown for this.

Comment: @KhairulIslam What code do you want me to show? However, using %40 worked

Comment: Perhaps you should consider accepting the answer that worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `@` is use to specify credential to access to a protected resource.

```
http://login:password@google.com/protectedfile.txt
```

So replace `@` by `%40`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `@@`, that should work.

This is a similar idea to other escape codes.

Or just try the HTML entity code instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, for example this is the url: Test/TestMail/testMVC@test.com.cshtml:

`routes.Add("Testroute", 
    new Route("Test/TestMail/{email}", 
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Test", action = "Testmail", param = UrlParameter.Optional }), 
    new MvcRouteHandler())
);`

Is this helping you out?